Build Qt 5.15.15 for android, error libspeechd.h not found
I need to build Qt 5.15 for android, I am on Ubuntu 22.04.3 LTS (GNU/Linux 5.15.153.1-microsoft-standard-WSL2 x86_64). I installed all the necessary, android SDK api 31, ndk r21e, ... but I finally get errors about libspeechd, ... not found.
I posted earlier a question about file crtbegin_so.o not found, solved changing android ndk from r21e to r27, but apparently, it's not a problem of android here.
My commande line is:
./qt5/configure -xplatform android-clang --disable-rpath -release -shared -android-arch arm64-v8a 
-android-ndk-platform android-31 -android-ndk /opt/Android/SDK/ndk/android-ndk-r21e -android-sdk 
/opt/Android/SDK -opensource -confirm-license -nomake examples -nomake tests -skip webglplugin -qt-zlib -qt-libpng -qt-libjpeg -skip webengine -prefix ./qt5-android-bin

make -j8

The error is that files flite.h and libspeechd.h are not found. How can't Qt find its own files?!
"Trying source 0 (type inline) of library flite ..." "+ cd /home/username/Documents/dvp/Qt/config.tests/flite && 
/home/username/Documents/dvp/Qt/qtbase/bin/qmake \"CONFIG -= qt debug_and_release app_bundle lib_bundle\" \"CONFIG += shared 
warn_off console single_arch\" -early \"CONFIG += cross_compile\" \'QMAKE_USE += flite\' \'QMAKE_LIBS_FLITE = 
-lflite_cmu_us_kal16 -lflite_usenglish -lflite_cmulex -lflite\' /home/username/Documents/dvp/Qt/config.tests/flite" "+ cd 
/home/username/Documents/dvp/Qt/config.tests/flite && MAKEFLAGS= /usr/bin/gmake" "> 
/opt/Android/SDK/ndk/27.2.12479018/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/bin/clang++ -c -target aarch64-linux-android31 
-fno-limit-debug-info -fPIC -fstack-protector-strong -DANDROID -O2 -fPIC  -I. 
-I/home/username/Documents/dvp/Qt/qt5/qtbase/mkspecs/android-clang -o main.o main.cpp" "> main.cpp:2:10: fatal error: 
\'flite/flite.h\' file not found" ">     2 | $${LITERAL_HASH}include <flite/flite.h>" ">       |          ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~" "> 1 
error generated." "> gmake: *** [Makefile:193: main.o] Error 1" " => source failed verification."
cache.speechd._KEYS_ = result msgs
cache.speechd.result = false
cache.speechd.msgs = "Trying source 0 (type pkgConfig) of library speechd ..." "pkg-config use disabled globally." "  => source 
produced no result." "Trying source 1 (type inline) of library speechd ..." "+ cd 
/home/username/Documents/dvp/Qt/config.tests/speechd && /home/username/Documents/dvp/Qt/qtbase/bin/qmake \"CONFIG -= qt 
debug_and_release app_bundle lib_bundle\" \"CONFIG += shared warn_off console single_arch\" -early \"CONFIG += cross_compile\" 
\'QMAKE_USE += speechd\' \'QMAKE_LIBS_SPEECHD = -lspeechd\' /home/username/Documents/dvp/Qt/config.tests/speechd" "+ cd 
/home/username/Documents/dvp/Qt/config.tests/speechd && MAKEFLAGS= /usr/bin/gmake" "> 
/opt/Android/SDK/ndk/27.2.12479018/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/bin/clang++ -c -target aarch64-linux-android31 
-fno-limit-debug-info -fPIC -fstack-protector-strong -DANDROID -O2 -fPIC  -I. 
-I/home/username/Documents/dvp/Qt/qt5/qtbase/mkspecs/android-clang -o main.o main.cpp" "> main.cpp:2:10: fatal error: 
\'libspeechd.h\' file not found" ">     2 | $${LITERAL_HASH}include <libspeechd.h>" ">       |          ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~" "> 1 
error generated." "> gmake: *** [Makefile:193: main.o] Error 1" " => source failed verification."
cache.libclang._KEYS_ = result msgs

I installed a lot of "speech" packages on my distribtion "apt install ..." but still have that problem.
In addition, I didn't use the options
  -flite ............... Enable Flite support [auto] (Unix only)
  -flite-alsa .......... Enable Flite with ALSA support [auto] (Unix only)
  -speechd ............. Enable speech dispatcher support [auto] (Unix only)

in my command line for configure so they shouldn't be enabled.
So what are those files and why Qt use and doesn't find them? Hoping there won't be any other files like that...
